# Multiple Definition Error in Static Library Project

Tags: c, static, arm, gnu

I have same function as `void myFunc();` in seperate 2 library as `libA.h` and `libB.h` in `myStaticLibrary` project.

I add this `myStaticLibrary.a` to my main project linker library.

I define only `libA.h` in my main code and ı use `myFunc()` but Compiler expect Multiple Defination error for `myFunc()`.

How can ı solve this problem. I use MCUxpresso ide.

Comment: Simple you cannot: this is [tag:c] not [tag:c++]. Why don't you change the names of functions?

Comment: I have a lof of libraries i cant change these names. If i redefine my all libraries and static library projet to c++ libraries and c++ library project, Will it dissolve ?

Comment: With [tag:c++] you have [Function overloading](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-overloading-c/)....I don't know if it is suitable for you.

Comment: Please show us a [example]. You can link to multiple libraries containing functions (or objects) with the same name under certain conditions, but before I spend a lot of time explaining that I need to know your exact problem.